# How to upload a file attachment to a new list item using Sharepoint Online remotely

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-item, client-object-model, soap

I need to upload a file to a new list item in Sharepoint Online from a clientapp.
The list exists allready, but I create new list items and tried to upload file as attachements.
I tried it over CSOM, but failed because the attachment folder for this item doesnt exist. It'll be created only if you manually upload something...

I think the same error happens if I try to upload the file over SOAP.

Upload to an existing list item with attachements is no problem at all.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?
Is there a workaround maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Below proof of concept, create item and add attachment via client object model.

```
var list = Context.Web.Lists.GetById(listId);
Context.Load(list);
Context.ExecuteQuery();

var item = list.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
item["Title"] = "New Item with attachment";
item.Update()
context.ExecuteQuery();

var attInfo           = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
attInfo.FileName      = "Attachment name";
attInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(attachmentData);

var att = item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo);
Context.Load(att);
Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                public static List<string> UploadDocuments<T>(ClientContext ctx,IList<HttpPostedFile> selectedFiles, T reqObj, int itemID)
                        {
                            List<Attachment> existingFiles = null;
                            List<string> processedFiles = null;
                            List<string> unProcessedFiles = null;
                            ListItem item = null;
                            FileStream sr = null;
                            AttachmentCollection attachments = null;
                            byte[] contents = null;
                            try
                            {
                                existingFiles = new List<Attachment>();
                                processedFiles = new List<string>();
                                unProcessedFiles = new List<string>();
            //Get the existing item
                                item = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(typeof(T).Name).GetItemById(itemID);
        //get the Existing attached attachments
                                attachments = item.AttachmentFiles;
                                ctx.Load(attachments);
                                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        //adding into the new List
                                foreach (Attachment att in attachments)
                                    existingFiles.Add(att);
        //For each Files which user has selected
                                foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in selectedFiles)
                                {
                                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    //If selected file not exist in existing item attachment
                                    if (!existingFiles.Any(x => x.FileName == fileName))
                                    {
//Added to Process List
                                        processedFiles.Add(postedFile.FileName);
                                    }
                                    else
                                        unProcessedFiles.Add(fileName);
                                }
//Foreach process item add it as an attachment
                                foreach (string path in processedFiles)
                                {
                                    sr = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
                                    contents = new byte[sr.Length];
                                    sr.Read(contents, 0, (int)sr.Length);
                                    var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
                                    attInfo.FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
                                    attInfo.ContentStream = sr;
                                    item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo);
                                    item.Update();
                                }
                                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                throw ex;
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                existingFiles = null;
                                processedFiles = null;
                                item = null;
                                sr = null;
                                attachments = null;
                                contents = null;
                                ctx = null;

                            }
                            return unProcessedFiles;
                        }
```